# 1 free shipping item in cart, minimum shipping fee still applied

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I understand why it is happening, but I'd like some help figuring a way around it. I suppose its probably a plugin.

I'm using weight based shipping calculations and its all fine. Except when I have a product using the free shipping field. I have a min shipping charge of $15, and that still gets applied even though there is 1 product in the cart and it has free shipping checked.

I need to be able to iterate over all cart items, and if all of them have free shipping checked, to zero out the shipping charge, or, effectively, circomvent the minimum shipping fee setting.